# PHP mail with attachment

Tags: php

Hello i'm trying to send email from form^) Here is my code

```
<?php
$to = "some email";
$from = "site";
$subject = "Resume";
$boundary = "---";

if (isset($_POST['ok'])){
    $filename = $_POST['fileField'];
    $resumeLink = $_POST['linkField'];
    $message = "Attachment: " .$resumeLink;
    /* Headers*/
    $headers = "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"";
    $body = "--$boundary\n";  
    /* Add message */
    $body .= "Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printablenn";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n";
    $body .= $message."\n";
    $body .= "--$boundary\n";
    $file = fopen($filename, "r"); //open file
    $text = fread($file, filesize($filename)); //read file
    fclose($file); //close file
    /* Add message type */
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n"; 
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n";
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($text))."\n";
    $body .= "--".$boundary ."--\n";
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){header("Location: /");}

}
?>
```

Attachment will send, but it size will be 1 byte without any content inside. Whats wrong?

Comment: i can't see the codeline where the data is sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly, but you've added header fields into mail body, you should add them in headers